# How to give common title for specific column headers on power bi visual (dashboard page) / report table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to create a common header for specific columns on power bi

[image]

In a normal table, it is not possible but I have tried grid table it is not showing my expected way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not find any option so I used a text box to create the header on the above columns

[image]

Comment: Hi, that is right you can't add a header like you can with excel, it is very much a work around.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this is still the case, please?

I only started looking at Power BI two days ago but I feel this is a pretty big omission.

In addition, the workaround doesn't work when the table has a horizontal scrollbar: the text box headers are static and (not unsurprisingly) do not move when the scrollbar is used.